# Stop some links (href containing certain string) from working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm attempting to stop some links on my site from working.

Here is my code:

Links:

```
<a href='http://mysite.home.com'>Home</a><br>
<a href='http://mysite.home.com/nextpage'>Next Page</a><br>
<a href='http://mysite.string.home.com'>Home 2</a><br>
<a href='http://mysite.string.home.com/otherpage'>Other Page</a>
```

Jquery:

```
<script>
    $("a[href*='.string.']").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('You cannot use this link');
    });
</script>
```

The goal is to stop the last two links (with href containing '.string.') from working and instead display the alert. However, this code isn't working and the links still work. What am I doing wrong?

The strange thing is the code works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/TzUN3/364/
but not on my site. I have the script and links both in the `<body>` of my page, script after the links. Is this correct?

Thanks.

Comment: Get any errors on your page?

Comment: The link is working fine. That's the expected behavior.

Comment: You've only shown us the case where it works correctly. You need to give enough information (or a complete example) to reproduce the problem, which you haven't done yet. Ultimately, we can't solve a problem we can't reproduce.

Comment: Check your console in developer tools for any errors as j08691 suggests, if there are any before the code you provided, that might be the reason why it doesn't work.

Comment: @j08691 WOW. Forgot to check, which reminded me to add <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> to my page, since I hadn't before. Now it works like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you all, problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Forgot to add

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

to my page. Feel like an idiot.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    // Jquery is ready
    // *= is contains
    $("a[href*='.string.']").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('You cannot use this link');
    }); 

});
```